# How to use array Adapter in Android?

Tags: java, android

I need to print name and surname to listview. I setup ewerything but the ArrayAdapter's code is underlying. I don't see my mistake. can you help me ?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);
    schedule_list = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.schedule_list);
    String[] menuItems = {"Serdar","Yazıcı"};
    //String[] listRow = new String[]{"photo","name","city"};
    int[] showList = new int[]{R.id.list_photo,R.id.list_name,R.id.list_city};
    ArrayAdapter<String> listViewAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            getActivity(),
            R.layout.listview_row,
            showList,
            menuItems);
    schedule_list.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

you should try a a SimpleAdapter instead of ArrayAdapter! going to work forsure :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code given below for custom Array Adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;



import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

   /**
    * Created by Zohaib Hassan on 11/28/2016.
    */

    public class InboxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InboxRow> {

   ArrayList<InboxRow> items;
    Context context;


    public InboxAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<InboxRow> 
    items) {
   super(context , resource , items);
   this.context = context;
    this.items = items;

   }



   @Override

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

// Get the data item for this position

InboxRow rowItem = getItem(position);

// Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view

ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag

if (convertView == null) {

    viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_row, null);

    viewHolder.tvUserName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_user_name_inbox);
    viewHolder.tvMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_message_inbox);
    viewHolder.tvTimeCount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_time_count_inbox);
    viewHolder.userProfilePic = (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inbox_profile_image);

    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

} else {

    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

}


/*CircleImageView ivProfileImage Set Background with Picasso*/

return convertView;

   }

   private static class ViewHolder {

     TextView tvUserName , tvMessage , tvTimeCount;
     CircleImageView userProfilePic;

 }

 }
```

And in your activity class use the sample code given below:

```
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.widget.ListView;



 import java.util.ArrayList;

 /**
 * Created by Zohaib Hassan on 11/28/2016.
  */

 public class InboxScreen extends Fragment {

ListView lvInbox;
ArrayList<InboxRow> inboxList;
InboxAdapter adapter;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_screen,container,false);


    lvInbox = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_inbox);

    inboxList = new ArrayList<InboxRow>();

    for (int a = 0 ; a < 20 ; a++)
    {
        inboxList.add(new InboxRow());
    }


    adapter = new InboxAdapter(getActivity() , R.layout.inbox_row , inboxList);
    lvInbox.setAdapter(adapter);

    return v;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling ListView in ArrayAdapter class, call ListVew and new ArrayAdaper in MainActivity.
Then set adapter to ListView onCreate.